# How to get an NPP instance in a Firebreath plugin?

Tags: plugins, cookies, npapi, firebreath

From within a class derived from FB::PluginCore (or FB::JSAPIAuto), for example in onPluginReady() or a JS method handler, I'd like to have access to the NPP instance. What is the best practice for getting this pointer?

The underlying goal is to be able to call NPN_SetValueForURL, to set cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call any of the NPN functions on the NpapiBrowserHost object, which is what the BrowserHost actually is.

```
FB::Npapi::NpapiBrowserHostPtr npapiHost = FB::ptr_cast<FB::Npapi::NpapiBrowserHost>(m_host);
```

I think it has SetValueForURL on it, but if it's missing you can always add it and submit a pull request; I'll accept it as long as it's reasonable.

Comment: IE is not NPAPI, so absolutely not. You ask about a NPP instance; there is no NPP instance in IE. More specifically, the cast will return a NULL pointer, so you can check it with if (npapiHost) { ... }